# is there a more elegant way to generate a wrapper/parent div for a map() of divs?

Tags: reactjs

I've written some code that outputs a group of divs based on an object array:

```
let groupOfDivs = myObjectArray.map(x => {
    let display = currentTab == x.name ? 'inline' : 'none';
    return (
        <div id={'divReportTab-' + x.name} style={{display: display}}>
            {x.value}
        </div>
    );
})
```

That generates the divs as expected but the problem is that I need to include that group of divs in a wrapper parent div.  In the render() function, I'm outputting the group of divs like this:

```
<div>{groupOfDivs}</div>
```

But is there a more elegant way to include the wrapper/parent div programmatically so I don't have to piece together the final output like that in render()?

Answer (score 0):

You do have some other patterns that would change your syntax some, but the result would ether way be more or less the same.

**Alternative 1:**

```
// Move the wrapping divs into your groupOfDivs-variable
let groupOfDivs = (
    <div>
        {myObjectArray.map((x) => {
            let display = currentTab == x.name ? 'inline' : 'none';
            return (
                <div id={'divReportTab-' + x.name} style={{ display: display }}>
                    {x.value}
                </div>
            );
        })}
    </div>
);

// Change the render to simply
{groupOfDivs}
```

**Alternative 2:**

```
// Inline the function directly in your render function
<div>
    {myObjectArray.map((x) => {
        let display = currentTab == x.name ? 'inline' : 'none';
        return (
            <div id={'divReportTab-' + x.name} style={{ display: display }}>
                {x.value}
            </div>
        );
    })}
</div>
```

**Alternative 3:**

```
// Move your array into its own component
<div>
    <MyComponent array={myObjectArray} currentTab={currentTab} />
</div>

// Create a component ether inside the same file or in a new file 

function MyComponent({array, currentTab}) {
    return array.map((x) => {
        let display = currentTab == x.name ? 'inline' : 'none';
        return (
            <div id={'divReportTab-' + x.name} style={{ display: display }}>
                {x.value}
            </div>
        );
    })          
}
```